# Xgboost forecasting model missing holiday period

Tags: machine-learning, regression, forecasting, data-science, xgboost

I am building a forecasting system to predict the number of cable subscribers that would disconnect at a given point in time. I am using Python and out of the different models i tried, XGBoost performs the best.

I have a self referential system in place which works in a moving window fashion, e.g, as i run out of actuals, i start using forecasted figures in my lags.

To build the forecasting system, i used previous 800 days of lags(disconnects a day), moving averages, ratios, seasonality, indicators for year, month, day, week etc. However, Holidays, is where is gets a little messed up. Initially i used just one column to indicate holidays of all sorts, but later i figured out that different holidays may have a different impact (some holidays cause high sales, some holidays cause churn) so i added a column for each holiday, i also added indicators for long weekends, for holidays which fall on a Sunday etc. i also added a columns for 'season' indicating festive period such as thanksgiving, new year holidays etc.

Even after adding so many holiday related columns, i largely miss the thanksgiving and the new year period. Although it does take care of holidays to some extent, it completely misses the spike. And as can be seen from the chart, the spikes are a trend and appear every year (orange). my forecast (grey) does address the holidays in dec 17, but it under forecasts, any idea on how that can be taken care of.
[image]

p.s. I tuned the xgboost hyperparameters using gridsearch

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, If you cleaned your data, removed outliers, your model will give a more stable prediction set overall, but it will fail to predict said outliers.

If you did clean the data, I'd play with the threshold, see the if the wider regular-day-errors balance with the ability to predict the higher spikes.